# Nautilus now has small icon and only one window

Tags: 10.10, nautilus

I run Ubuntu 10.10. At first, icons in Nautilus got smaller and zoom didn't work. Then when I started again it opens in only one window and lost his selections in "View". To show what I mean here is the screen shot:

[image]

Last time I installed PHP-GTK and all sorts of libraries that is needed for that and was working fine, but the next time I turn on computer I got this nautilus behaviour  and bluetooth icon in panel which I removed long time ago.

When I do `sudo nautilus` it opens fine except icons which are still smaller than before. It opens with this message:

```
Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension

** (nautilus:8100): WARNING **: Failed to get the current CK session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '8100'

(nautilus:8100): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


(nautilus:8100): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed

(nautilus:8100): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed

(nautilus:8100): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed

(nautilus:8100): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed

(nautilus:8100): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed

(nautilus:8100): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed

(nautilus:8100): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
```

How can I get back to the old nautilus?

Comment: Go to View and select the Show lateral pane ... and while you're there up the size of the icons...

Comment: And don't use `sudo`to run GUI applications use `gksu`.

Comment: that's where the problem is. That "show" options in "View" have dissapeared.

Comment: do you  also have thunar installed?

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu but I don't think I had the thunar installed at that time.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: Not any more since I reinstalled. It can be closed. Thank you

Comment: flagged for closure with permission user1079002